# How to create a numpy array of boost::python::object types

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to create a 2x2 numpy array of python objects:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::numpy::initialize();
    boost::python::tuple shape = boost::python::make_tuple(2, 2);
    boost::python::object obj;
    boost::python::numpy::dtype dt = boost::python::numpy::dtype(obj);
    boost::python::numpy::ndarray array = boost::python::numpy::empty(shape, dt);
    std::cout << "Datatype is: " << boost::python::extract<char const *> boost::python::str(array.get_dtype())) << std::endl;
}
```

But the output is "Datatype is: float64" rather than a python object type.

What am I doing wrong?

I suspect I'm misusing the dtype constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `dtype` constructor correctly; it's `obj` that's causing the trouble.

The default construction `boost::python::object obj;` sets `obj` as the `'None'` Python object. The `dtype` associated with `'None'` is a `NPY_DEFAULT` array descriptor type. And that maps to a `double` when creating the `numpy` array, which explains your output. (That makes sense from a Python perspective - the default `numpy` array type is a double precision floating point type.)

You can constuct a `dtype` with an object type (`NPY_OBJECT`) using

```
boost::python::numpy::dtype dt = boost::python::numpy::dtype(boost::python::object("O"));
```

which, in your case, is the fix. I've also taken the liberty of using an anonymous temporary which is how it's done in the Boost documentation. The `"O"` denotes the object type.